# After Magento admin login, the dashboard screen continuously loading

Tags: magento2

[image]

After the Magento admin login, the dashboard screen continuously loading.

Please provide a solution to this problem?

Comment: did you run this command `php bin/magento s:static-content:d -f`???

Comment: actually the issue is your script and CSS not loading properly, so, please try to run all commands. sudo chmod -R 777 pub/* var/* generated/*
   
  sudo rm -rf var/cache/* generated/* var/tmp/* pub/static/* var/page_cache* var/di/*

  sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

  sudo chmod -R 777 pub/* var/* generated/*
  sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
  sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
  sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
  sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
  sudo chmod -R 777 pub/* var/* generated/*

Comment: Please check the console for any error.